# Chrome extension: grab URL from activeTab and paste to another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

(ITERATION 2 COMES AFTER THIS PART. PLEASE SCROLL DOWN A BIT)
I am trying to build an extension that would grab the URL of a youtube page (which is activeTab), and then it finds another tab with the title of 'Village', grabs an element in that DOM, and pastes the link.

I seem to be having trouble with my `chrome.tabs.query({'title:})` or my `getElementById` from the not active tab.

Could someone please weigh in?

```
console.log('popupjs loads')

//get current URL of youtube or soundcloud
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  currentURL = tabs[0].url;
  console.log(currentURL);
  //finds tab with village
  chrome.tabs.query({'title': 'Village'}, function(findVillage){
    //if there is a tab
    //if there is a current user
    //get link
    var myElement = document.getElementById("post-link"); 
    //create text with url of youtube or soundcloud
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(currentURL);
    //paste link
    myElement.append(textnode); <--- error happens here
    //press submit button
    //else
    //message error

  });
});
```

This is the error

```
Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
    at null.callback (chrome-extension://knmmfcephkakihklkejdofcijfpjgmmf/popping.js:17:14)
    at null.callback (chrome-extension://knmmfcephkakihklkejdofcijfpjgmmf/popping.js:9:15)
```

I understand that it says myElement does not have an object. I feel like there is a problem at the chrome tabs query for 'title'

Thank you!

---

----------ITERATION 2--------------------
I had a look at the link suggested in the comments, however, I am not having the same problem. I simply did not explain myself well enough.

I have refactored the code as best as I could, trying to make it more clear

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  currentURL = tabs[0].url;
  console.log(currentURL);

  //iterate through tabs
  for (i=0; i <= chrome.tabs.length; i++) {
    //see if tab is mywebsit
    console.log(tabs[i].url);
    if (tabs[i].url == "mywebsite.com") {
      //if mywebsite, make that tab the active tab
      chrome.tabs.update(window.tabs[i].id, {active: true});
      //find the link-post text field, and paste in the youtube link
      document.getElementById("post-link").appendChild(currentURL);
    };
  };
});
```

I read through the links posted and through more docs. I am no longer getting the no object error. Instead I now get no error, but the code only makes it as far as the `console.log(currentURL);`. It doesn't log the `console.log(tabs[i].url);`

To iterate again: What I would like to do is:

1. grab the link from the currentTab (which happens successfully)
2. then I want to iterate through the other currentWindow tabs.
3. I want to see which tab has the url "mywebsite.com".
4. I then want to make "mywebsite.com" the activeTab,
5. grab a DOM text field in the activeTab,
6. add the url from step 1 into the DOM (text field) of step 4

Thank you for your help!

Comment: when referring to the document in the second callback, is that the document of the other tab, or the document of the currently selected tab?

Comment: It's the document of the other tab.

Comment: The only thing I notice here is that append wont work with vanilla JS.  appendChild will

Comment: I do not think my question is the same as the link. In their problem, they were having trouble modifying the page rather than the extension. With my issue, I am able to access the chrome window. I have refactored some of my code and posted a clarification.  Please see "SECOND ITERATION" on the top post.

Comment: Your code makes little sense. I highly recommend [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You're trying to iterate through `chrome.tabs` - which isn't a collection of tabs but a collection of functions to work with them; then you access `tabs[i]`, when `tabs` is unchanged since it was set by `query` - and is at most 1 element array. Then, there's `window.tabs` for some reason. And finally, the duplicate pertains to your point 4 - if you want to change something in a tab, that's the correct dupe.